# Missing Private Key for iOS Dist Cert

Tags: ios, app-store

I've found a lot of information about this, but nothing that quite helps me with my situation. I lost my hard drive a few weeks ago. I've since bought and configured a new system, but now I have to drop a new version of an app in the app store. I've re-downloaded 3 certificates, including the distribution cert, and the distribution profile, but XCode reports that my distribution profile is invalid (specifically, "Valid signing identity not found").

After a lot of searching and reading, it seems that the issue is a missing private key, but I have no idea how to rectify that. I do have a recent (SuperDuper) backup of the old machine, but opening the old Keychain Access app only shows me what's on my current machine (or so it appears -- I don't see anything different). That would be my only window for retrieving the old key. Ditto opening the old copy of XCode and looking at its Organizer.

If I try to revoke my existing distribution cert, I get warned that all of my existing apps (all of which are signed with that cert) will cease to function. I definitely don't want that.

Do I have any options here? Apple's system of certs and profiles admittedly baffles me so I'm hoping that there's some kind of recourse for re-establishing contact with my distribution key or creating a new cert without completely hosing up everything that already exists.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the intermediate certificate and following the procedure to get a certificate signing request? That would be the best way to get a valid certificate from Apple if you don't have the originals.

Comment: I did download & install the "WWDR intermediate certificate". I also have the original signing request (if that helps me at all). All I _seem_ to be missing is the private key.

Comment: I'm sure it's obvious in retrospect, but you should keep a backup of all your certs with private keys. I export them all out with a long password and leave them in place like DropBox or a drive with automatic backups. For fixing the issue, I know Xcode keeps copies and keeps re-installing them in my keychain if I try to re-compile/archive/distribute archives. I've also had the iPhone Configuration Utility make old certificates pop back into my keychain for unknown reason. I'd love to tell you where they are being cached for those apps, but I just don't know.

Comment: @DBD Yeah, this is my first iOS app and it's built using Titanium so I was/am completely unfamiliar with the App Store. I did hang onto the CSR thinking I might need it again, but it never occurred to me to hang on to the private key. Obvious in retrospect, indeed. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the old Keychain Access app didn't work because it loads all the data from the compute it's running on. What you'll need to do is get the old .keychain file and open it with Keychain Access.

In your backup, find `/Users/USER_NAME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` and make a copy of it. Next, you'll want to rename it to something else like `oldlogin.keychain` to prevent it from conflicting with your new login keychain. Then just double click on `oldlogin.keychain` to open it Keychain Access. It may ask you for a password to access the keychain, it should be your login password from before you lost your hard drive. Once its unlocked, you can drag anything you want from `oldlogin` to `login` including the private key.

Comment: You, sir, have just saved my bacon. I believe that got me where I needed to get. Danke.